# "Unable to deserialize the execution context" when creating tasklet with StepBuilder

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I recently started using Spring batch (and quite new to Java) and now I am trying to create a tasklet which creates a table in a database.

```
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Configure {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            SpringApplication.run(Configure.class, args);
        }    
    @Bean
        public Job AggregateTransactionsFromDatabaseToXML(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                                                          StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                                                          Tasklets tasklets){return jobBuilderFactory.get("etl")
                                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                                    .start(tasklets.createTempTable(null, null))
                                    .build();}

        @Configuration
        static class Tasklets{
            @Bean
            Step createTempTable(DataSource dataSource, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
                StepBuilder createTempTable = stepBuilderFactory.get("create temp table");
                String sql = "CREATE TABLE DatabaseName.TableName\n" +
                        "(\n" +
                        "    column1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,\n" +
                        "    column2 DATE NOT NULL,\n" +
                        "    column3 DECIMAL NOT NULL,\n" +
                        "    column4 BIGINT NOT NULL,\n" +
                        "    column5 BIGINT NOT NULL\n" +
                        ")";
                return createTempTable.tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).execute(sql);
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                                      .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                                      .build();
            }
}
}
```

I am getting an error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize the execution context.`

I have no clue how this is possible.

I looked online for examples with the StepBuilder, but could not find any usefull on for my task.
[TaskletStepBuilder example](https://github.com/EBIvariation/examples/blob/master/spring-batch-dynamic-workflow/src/main/java/embl/ebi/variation/examples/dynamicworkflow/SimpleDeciderConfiguration.java) and 
[Reader en Writer example](https://aboullaite.me/spring-batch-tutorial-with-spring-boot/)

Am I using the StepBuilder wrong? Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

The problem has been solved: I didn't configure the spring application context. This is apparently important.

Comment: what source tutorials you using ( if you can provide ) ?Also, share full code. Are you using any kind of frameworks like Spring Boot etc too? How are you setting up your data sources and what type of DB you use?

Comment: I am using spring boot and mysql. The datasource is configured inside application.properties (it works on other steps that I run instead of this [https://github.com/EBIvariation/examples/blob/master/spring-batch-dynamic-workflow/src/main/java/embl/ebi/variation/examples/dynamicworkflow/SimpleDeciderConfiguration.java]and [https://aboullaite.me/spring-batch-tutorial-with-spring-boot/]

Comment: Correct your links, both giving 404. Include in question if possible.

Comment: Do you have job meta tables like `BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE` , `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` etc set up? These are the tables where spring batch keeps job meta data.

Comment: Yes, I got those. Everything works now. I also changed tasklets.createTempTable(null, null) to tasklets.createTempTable(null, stepBuilderFactory).

Comment: Okay, so I guess, you should answer your own question as what was root cause and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved: I didn't configure the spring application context. This is apparently important.

I also changed tasklets.createTempTable(null, null) to tasklets.createTempTable(null, stepBuilderFactory).